# retrieving null date from database to vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datepicker

i am having a problem in recovering a null date from my database into datepicker in vb.net.

i was able to save a datein mysql with a null value but can't retrieve it to datepicker.

i tried this code but it doesn't work.

```
  If reader.IsDBNull(0) Then
                            Return
                        Else
                            refdate.Text = reader.GetString("refdate")
                        End If
```

my code for retrieving is

```
 Try

            If e.RowIndex >= 0 Then

                Dim row As DataGridViewRow
                row = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex)
                forid.Text = row.Cells("id").Value.ToString

                Try
                    connection.Open()
                    Dim sel As String

                        sel = "select * from recordtracker where id ='" & forid.Text & "'"
                        com = New MySqlCommand(sel, connection)
                        reader = com.ExecuteReader

                    While reader.Read

                        Cancel.Show()
                        Clear.Hide()
                        rdate.Enabled = False
                        rfromtbx.Enabled = False

                        doctype.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown


                        ID.Text = reader.GetInt32("id")
                        doctype.Text = reader.GetString("Type_of_Document")
                        itemtbx.Text = reader.GetString("Items")
                        rfromtbx.Text = reader.GetString("Received_From")
                        rdate.Text = reader.GetString("Received_Date")
                        remarks.Text = reader.GetString("Remarks")
                        margnote.Text = reader.GetString("Marginal_Note")
                        reftotbx.Text = reader.GetString("Referred_To")
                        acttaken.Text = reader.GetString("Action_Taken")

                        'refdate.Text = reader.GetString("refdate")

                        'If reader.Read() Then
                        If reader.IsDBNull(0) Then
                            Return
                        Else
                            refdate.Text = reader.GetString("refdate")
                        End If
                            Delete.Show()
                        ' End If
                    End While

                Catch ex As Exception
                    MsgBox(ex.Message)
                End Try
```

any help is appreciated.

Comment: reader.IsDBNull(0) <<< doesn't this mean, index zero (0)? and isn't index zero, the ID and not the date?

Comment: try this>> [if isDbNull(reader.GetString("refdate")) then] ... instead of [If reader.IsDBNull(0) Then]

Comment: i tried [if isDbNull(reader.GetString("refdate")) then] still getting error "data is null. this method or property cannot be called for null values".. my code now looks like this           
`If IsNothing(reader.GetString("refdate")) Then
                                refdate.Checked = False
Else
ID.Text = reader.GetInt32("id")
doctype.Text = reader.GetString("Type_of_Document")  
refdate.Text = reader.GetString("refdate")
 End If`

Comment: try this>> if isDbNull(reader("refdate")) then

Comment: it worked...thanks..i'll let you know if i encounter some issues..thanks again

Comment: @MAC please add your comment as an answer for future references.

Comment: @Saleem I already did. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1):

For future use, this was the answer needed by the asker.

`reader.IsDBNull(0)` gets the value of index zero which I presume that `refdate` is not in the first index.

Using `reader.GetString("refdate")` gets the `String` value; therefore, when retrieving `null` value, it returns error so better use `isDbNull(reader("refdate"))` to check if the field is null or not. To get the String value, you can simply use `reader("refdate").toString`